# Update the checkbox value of an html page

Tags: mysql, ajax, html, stored-procedures

Good morning,

I have a question regarding the setting of checkbox values in an html page. The question may sound quite vague, as I am not quite sure how to achieve this.

What I would like to achieve is to retrieve a set of boolean values  from a mysql database, most probably by running a stored procedure.

Based on this set of values returned, I would like that the checkboxes of my html page are updated accordingly. As I would like this script to run every 1 or 2 seconds and I do not want to refresh the whole html page so frequently, I have heard that ajax might be the answer to my question.

So for my question, do you have kind of recommendations and/or examples, tutorials for a newbie starting from scratch with this ajax technology?

Many thanks for your kind help and have a great day.

Best wishes,
Laurent

Comment: how the checkboxes and booleans are related? that's why you should post your attempted code too.

Comment: I should have been more specific maybe but currently I have no code, hence my request to start from scratch. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html part:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"> I have a car<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Truck"> I have a truck<br>
```

Ajax part:

```
var arr, i;
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "ajaxfile.php",
  dataType: "json"
}).done(function( data ) {
    arr = $.parseJSON(data);
    i = 0;
    $(':checkbox').each(function(){
        this.checked = arr[i++];  //assuming ajax file returned boolean values in json array.
     });
});
```

I Guess if it works you can do the rest. [Read This](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to know more about working with ajax.

Comment: Thanks a lot Asif, very much appreciated.
Can I ask you an additional question regarding the sample ajax code you wrote? How is the link established between the name of the checkboxes (Bike, Car, Truck) and the loop ?

Again a big thank you for your kind help.

Comment: @Laurent wc :) It would be great if you can accept my answer. I assumed that array of booelans are in the same order as the checkboxes because you didn't answer my question then.

Comment: yeah i can see that.. thanks :) if you've any more query regarding this question let me know.

Comment: Thanks Asif ^_^
If I will extract some keyValuePairs from the database into a JSON string which would look like this "{"Bike":"true","Car":"true","Truck":"false"}", how should I modify the code to be sure that the correct value will be applied to the correct checkbox id?

Another question regarding the html sample: was it on purpose to have 3 times the name vehicle or should I take the same name as the value (i.e. name = "Bike" value ="Bike") ?